# Only one row is getting fetched

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql

I was trying to fetch the top 10 results from API to my Nodejs express server and store them in the PostgreSQL database and then using express to get the above-stored data from the database to the front end.

But only one row is getting fetched and it is being printed 10 times.

Below is my index.js code

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

// Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint
request.open('GET', 'https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/tickers', true)

request.onload = function () {
    // Begin accessing JSON data here
    if (this.status === 200) {
        let obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        let content = document.querySelector("#content");
        let unit = document.querySelector(".unit");
        // To get object length
        // let ln = Object.keys(obj).length
        str = ""
        str2 = ""
        let count = 0;

        for (key_1 in obj) {
            while (count < 10) {
                let name = obj[key_1].name;
                let last = obj[key_1].last;
                let buy = obj[key_1].buy;
                let sell = obj[key_1].sell;
                let volume = obj[key_1].volume;
                let base_unit = obj[key_1].base_unit;
                count += 1
                str += `
            <tr class="values">
            <td class="index">${count}</td>
            <td class="name">${name}</td>
            <td class="last">&#8377; ${last}</td>
            <td class="bs">&#8377; ${buy} / &#8377; ${sell}</td>
            <td class="volume">${volume}</td>
            <td class="base_unit">${base_unit}</td>
            </tr>
            `
                str2 += `
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">${base_unit.toUpperCase()}</a></li>
            `
            }
        }
        content.innerHTML += str
        unit.innerHTML += str2

    }
    else {
        console.log("File Not Found!!!")
    }
}
request.send()
```

This is my first XMLHttpRequest, I have searched on net since last night, but am not able to get anything that can help me out with this.

Below I have also attached my index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="left">
                <img src="./logo.png" alt="" width="300" height="1000">
            </div>
            <div class="tags">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1"
                        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        INR
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1"
                        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        BTC
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu unit" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="connect-button">
                    <span><img src="./telgram.png" alt=""></span>
                    <span><a href="#">Connect Telegram</a></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="main">
        <table id="content">
            <tr class="heading">
                <td>
                    <h3>#</h3>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h3>name</h3>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h3>Last</h3>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h3>Buy / Sell Price</h3>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h3>volume</h3>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h3>base_unit</h3>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

Any help is highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Add sample API response

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
for (entity in obj) {

    let name = entity.name;
    let last = entity.last;
    let buy = entity.buy;
    let sell = entity.sell;
    let volume = entity.volume;
    let base_unit = entity.base_unit;
    
    ...html creation
}
```

Comment: Okay , will try this out!!